# C++ Volatile Type Quantifier Position In Variable Definition

Tags: c++, optimization, volatile

I have been doing some research and haven't found a good answer and I am hoping for some better understanding.
I know how to use `volatile` but have a question about what it does when its placement is different in variable declarations, for example.

- `volatile int * ptr;`

The integer pointed to is `volatile` and when reading/writing to this memory location always go to the memory location.

- `int * volatile ptr;`

The pointer value itself is `volatile` and when reading/writing to this memory location always go to the memory location.

It's a subtle difference, but from what I can tell the difference is something like this.

```
volatile int * foo;
int * volatile bar;
volatile int testInt = 5;
 ------------------------
|          0x020         | - 0x000 (foo), memory location 0x000 can be cached.
 ------------------------ 
|          0x020         | - 0x010 (bar), memory location 0x010 can't be cached.
 ------------------------
|           5            | - 0x020 (testInt)
 ------------------------
```

My question is what if the volatile quantifier isn't on a pointer type, for example.

```
volatile int foo = 5;
int volatile bar = 5;
 ------------------------
|            5           | - 0x000 (foo), memory location 0x000 can't be cached.
 ------------------------ 
|            5           | - 0x004 (bar), memory location 0x004 can't be cached.
 ------------------------
```

Don't these two declarations do the same thing for non-pointer declarations?

Comment: Yes they do the same thing.

Comment: Is your question just - is `volatile int` the same type as `int volatile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the modifier keyword order is flexible. It does the same thing on the left or the right of the type. The same thing goes for *const*.

I prefer the modifier ***after*** the type, because it allows you to read from right to left to get the plain-English definition.

```
int volatile * foo; // "foo is a pointer to a volatile int"
int * volatile foo;  // "foo is a volatile pointer to an int"
int const * foo; // "foo is a pointer to a constant int"
int * const foo; // "foo is a constant pointer to an int"
```

So I self-standardize on

```
int volatile foo;
```